# Limit number of Rows inserted into a Table

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can we restrict a table to have fixed number of rows?
for example if i give Limit as 20, then 20 rows can be inserted into it and after that table should indicate the limit has been exceeded.

EXAMPLE: IF we create a trigger

```
 CREATE TRIGGER log AFTER INSERT ON TEST_TABLE
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES(....);
 SELECT COUNT(COL) FROM TEST_TABLE;
 END;
```

This is not giving me the count as soon as i enter a row into the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Trigger before Insert on That **table**.
In Trigger you can check for count for records that same table has.

Check [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) link for Creating Trigger.

Comment: SQLite's SQL triggers are not very sophisticated. So, I'm wondering if it is easily possible to implement that trigger without resorting to writing some extension in C. How would you implement this trigger?

Comment: @LukasEder `... BEGIN SELECT RAISE(FAIL, 'more than 20') WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable) >= 20; END;`

Comment: @CL.: OK, it's *that* easy :-) That should go into an answer, then!