# How to limit Number of rows to be stored in Sqlite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can we restrict a table to have fixed number of rows? for example if i give Limit as 20, then 20 rows can be inserted into it and after that table should indicate the limit has been exceeded.
If we use a trigger like this we cant get number of rows after each entry.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER log AFTER INSERT ON TEST_TABLE
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES(....);
 SELECT COUNT(COL) FROM TEST_TABLE;
 END;
```

Am new to sqlite, kindly help me guys.

Comment: You asked the same question here: [Limit number of Rows inserted into a Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272583/limit-number-of-rows-inserted-into-a-table) Please ask there for clarification or more help if needed (though the answer there seems pretty clear to me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tg_limit 
BEFORE INSERT ON Table1
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN 15 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1) + 1
BEGIN
  SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'Limit has been exceeded');
END
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d82b0/3)** demo

or

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_limit 
BEFORE INSERT ON Table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'Limit has been exceeded')
   WHERE 15 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1) + 1;
END
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/71221/1)** demo

Comment: @ peterm Thanku very much for the info.. I was excatly looking for this....